# Ampersand character is escaped in text. This breaks the link

Tags: html, url

Following is the activation link prepared at server side and sent in an email. When it's viewed in html and click on this link, there is no issue. When opened in text mode, '&' before the emailId is rendered as '&' This breaks the activation link.

> If you're unable to click on the link, copy the URL below and paste it
>   into your browser
>   manually.
> https://test.abc.com//#_resetpassword?token=EUDaPcNf8bctWAed0w$$&emailId=xyz.lmn@abc.com

When email is viewed in text mode:

> If you're unable to click on the link, copy the URL below and paste it
>   into your browser
>   manually.
> https://test.abc.com//#_resetpassword?token=EUDaPcNf8bctWAed0w$$&emailId=xyz.lmn@abc.com

Any help?

Comment: use `htmlspecialchars_decode()` OR `htmlspecialchars()` OR `html_entity_decode()` function for decode HTML Special characters into text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this issue got resolved.
We used npm enj module and we escaped & with <%= %>. It replaced & with & However, <%- %> did the trick. It kept & as it is. This worked for me in both html mode and also in text mode.

Answer (score 0):

is this processed through PHP? there may be a filter for that output. e.g. mysql_real_escape_string-like function or a http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php filter_input (or similair function) that sanitizes the string output.

Comment: server side, it's nodeJs